# How to remove localStorage data starting with a certain string?

Tags: javascript, firebase, local-storage

I want to remove Firebase-related localStorage. I tried this:

```
  let arr = [] // Array to hold the keys
  // Iterate over localStorage and insert the keys that meet the condition into arr
  for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) { // eslint-disable-line
    console.log(localStorage.key(i)) // eslint-disable-line
    if (localStorage.key(i).substring(0,3) == 'firebase:') { // eslint-disable-line
      arr.push(localStorage.key(i)) // eslint-disable-line
    }
  }
  // Iterate over arr and remove the items by key
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    localStorage.removeItem(arr[i]) // eslint-disable-line
  }
```

However they are not being removed at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
substring(0,3) == 'firebase:'
```

This can never be true. You're getting a string 3 characters long and comparing it to "firebase:". Just change your 3 to a 9 so it looks like this:

```
substring(0, 9) == 'firebase:'
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use any extra array and a loop.

```
for (key in localStorage) {
  if (key.substring(0,9) == 'firebase:') {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

u have to specify the substrig totally 9 charatcers starts with 0

```
 localStorage.setItem("abc" , "heelo");
       localStorage.setItem("abc2" , "firebase:")
        for (obj in localStorage) {
      if (localStorage[obj].substring(0,9) == 'firebase:') {
        localStorage.removeItem(obj);
      }
    }
    console.log(localStorage)
```