# Using localStorage and sessionStorage as tree of elements

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

During application refactoring I very lately found out about localStorage and sessionStorage are key-value storages, so question: is thee any JavaScript implementation for using localStorage, sessionStorage as JSON, and stay ability to easely edit them via browser debug tools?

Example:
We create some value for key application, it have sub-keys like settings, connection, they have subkeys for properties.

So, easy way to interact them like this:

```
if (localStorage.application.connection.URI.slice(0, 5) === "https") { ... }
```

And, if we need to destroy branch for properties and re-init them:

```
localStorage.application.connection = undefined;
```

Any way to do this? I know, I can use

```
if (localStorage.getItem("application.connection.URI").slice(0, 5) === "https") { ... }
```

And (thx to this answer [How to remove localStorage data starting with a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176438/how-to-remove-localstorage-data-starting-with-a-certain-string#38176473))

```
for (key in localStorage) {
    if (key.substring(0,22) == 'application.connection') {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
}
```

But it is slightly hard to read and use.

Any suggestions? And sorry for my english.

Comment: Maybe JSON.encode and JSON.parse is your answer?

Comment: No-no, I know about it, but it cannot be obviously and fast edited in runtime. Or something that can expose JSON to localStorage values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late but here you go: I implemented [DotStorage](https://github.com/Farbdose/DotStorage) as a hacky solution for this about a year ago.

It's neither maintained nor fully tested but it does the job.
...I just checked the repo: be aware that you need [pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) for this to work....

Don't use it for big things though as this is realized by automatically wrapping objects and their properties in proxies - **implementing deep change detection by trapping everything.**

**Usage:** like any other Javascript object, it's just persistent:

```
dotStorage.Hello = "World";
// reload page
console.assert(dotStorage.Hello == "World");
```

You can take a look at my JSFiddle based test file [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Farbdose/fufsbgef/)

**Example:**

```
var myObj = {"New": "object"};

// save the object
dotStorage.refTest = myObj;

// get proxified instance
myObj = dotStorage.refTest;

// change nested properties
myObj.New = {"nested": {"otherObject": [0, 1]}};
console.log(JSON.stringify(dotStorage.refTest.New));

// reload the page ------------------------------------------

// change more nested properties
myObj.New.nested = 2;

// everything is still there
console.log(JSON.stringify(dotStorage.refTest.New));
```